# where to add eventhandler

Tags: c#, events

I have just passed one well known test and I am curious to know answer to the question:

"Scenario: You are writing a form that has a "Start Task" button and a "Task Info" button. The "Task Info" button starts disabled, but whenever the "Start Task" button is clicked, the "Task Info" is enabled and an event handler is added to it that sends a status report to the printer. Once the task completes, the "Task Info" button is disabled again until "Start Task" is clicked once more. A task may take many minutes to complete, and sometimes status reports need to be printed both near the beginning and near the end of the task.

This functions perfectly for the first task but you find that for subsequent tasks, extra status reports are sent to the printer, wasting paper and effort sorting through them.
Based on the scenario above, how do you solve the problem?

Choices:

1. Disable the "Task Info" button within the "Task Info" button click handler.
2. Disable the "Start Task" button within the "Task Info" button click handler, then re-enable it when the task finishes.
3. Implement the IDisposable interface for the "Start Task" button and the "Task Info" button.
4. Increment a counter within the "Task Info" button click handler, and have the rest of the code only execute when the counter's value is zero.
5. Add the event handler for the "Task Info" button in the form's constructor rather than "Start Task" button's handler

I personally prefer answer # 5. But it is intersting to know the community point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the correct solution is number 5.